Cannot recover the entire file when transmitting/receiving using LimeSDR in GNU Radio
I am building a QPSK transmitter/receiver using the QPSK method in GNU Radio. I am able to recover data at very high accuracy, but it seems that my receiver is unable to capture the final chunks of data. For example, if I send a 10MB file from my Transmitter, the receiver somehow only captures the 1st 9MB of the file. This happens regardless of the file size, as I am always losing the final chunk of data of the file at my receiver. I have captured the raw IQ data from my receiver to see if its length matches the size of my file and it size is nowhere near what it should be, so I know the problem doesn't lie on the receiver side.
I am a bit stumped as to why this is happening. I have tried adding delay before transmitter/after receivers, played with the buffer sizes, different sampling rates/center frequencies and gain settings but the problem still remains. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my transmitter flowgraph for reference

And my Receiver flowgraph

You can see from this graph that my received data is nowhere near my transmitted data

